# How to efficiently remove junk above headers in an .xls file

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a number of .xls datasheets which I am looking to clean and merge.
Each data sheet is generated by a larger system which cannot be changed.
The method that generates the data sets displays the selected parameters for the data set. (E.G [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMdYh.png)) I am looking to automate the removal of these.

The number of rows that this takes up varies, so I am unable to blanket remove x rows from each sheet. Furthermore, the system that generates the report arbitrarily merges cells in the blank sections to the right of the information.

Currently I am attempting what feels like a very inelegant solution where I convert the file to a CSV, read it as a string and remove everything before the first column.

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel('InputFile.xls', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('Change1.csv', encoding='utf-8')

with open("Change1.csv") as f:
    s = f.read() + '\n'

a=(s[s.index("Col1"):])
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in a.split('\n')])
```

This works but it seems wildly inefficient:

1. Multiple format conversions
2. Reading every line in the file when the only rows being altered occur within first ~20
3. Dataframe ends up with column headers shifted over by one and must be re-aligned (Less concern)

With some of the files being around 20mb, merging a batch of 8 can take close to 10 minutes.

Comment: after load data into df find row index with columns and drop all above them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hacky, but an idea to speed up your process, by doing some operations directly on your dataframe. Considering you know your first column name to be `Col1`, you could try something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('InputFile.xls', index_col=None)

# Find the first occurrence of "Col1"
column_row = df.index[df.iloc[:, 0] == "Col1"][0]

# Use this row as header
df.columns = df.iloc[column_row]

# Remove the column name (currently an useless index number)
del df.columns.name

# Keep only the data after the (old) column row
df = df.iloc[column_row + 1:]

# And tidy it up by resetting the index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

This should work for any dynamic number of header rows in your Excel (`xls` & `xlsx`) files, as long as you know the title of the first column...

Comment: I like the look of this, as the `Col1` will always have that name, currently it is bringing up a `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` but I'll have a tinker around as this is likely due to me shoe-horning the code in

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you need help. I created a file similar to your screenshot and it works fine.

Comment: Solved - `Col1` was actually in column B
This is the same for every sheet being used so can easily be worked around

Comment: Yes, noticeably so. Previously to when I ran this process on three sets of data sheets it would take around 15 minutes to finish. Now it takes about 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of junk rows, you skip them using "skiprows",

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel('InputFile.xls', index_col=None, skiprows=2)
```